# How to get cronjob to save an excel file every 5 minutes?

Tags: python, excel, cron

I have an excel sheet that gets realtime stock prices, but python can only read the last saved version of the excel file, and not the excel file as it is running. Therefore I need to know how to autosave the file every 5 minutes so that python's xlrd can read the most recently saved excel file.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? What have you tried?

Comment: Where does the excel sheet pick up the prices from? Maybe you can poll the source directly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do that with a cron job (or if it's even possible). I think probably what you want to do is use a macro to autosave it. Maybe [something like this](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=84455).